# why does passing an object by value generate smaller assembly?

Tags: c++, reference

I'm playing around with references in C++ on a Cortex-M4 and I noticed that when I change the argument of a function to pass the object by value I get smaller assembly code.

```
struct Foo
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int bar[128];
    float f;
    float b;
    char hello;
    int * i;
};

Foo &getFoo(void)
{
    static Foo _f;
    return _f;
}

void passFoo(Foo& f)
{
    f.x = 0;
    return;
}

int main(void)
{
    Foo & f = getFoo();
    passFoo(f);
}
```

Assembly output:

```
getFoo():
        ldr     r0, .L3
        bx      lr
.L3:
        .word   .LANCHOR0
passFoo(Foo&):
        movs    r3, #0
        str     r3, [r0]
        bx      lr
main:
        ldr     r3, .L7
        movs    r0, #0
        str     r0, [r3]
        bx      lr
.L7:
        .word   .LANCHOR0
```

[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/ds8es5GnG)

If I change the argument of `passFoo` to take `Foo` by value not by reference the output assembly is smaller.

```
struct Foo
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int bar[128];
    float f;
    float b;
    char hello;
    int * i;
};

Foo &getFoo(void)
{
    static Foo _f;
    return _f;
}

void passFoo(Foo f)
{
    f.x = 0;
    return;
}

int main(void)
{
    Foo & f = getFoo();
    passFoo(f);
}
```

Assembly output:

```
getFoo():
        ldr     r0, .L3
        bx      lr
.L3:
        .word   .LANCHOR0
passFoo(Foo):
        sub     sp, sp, #16
        stm     sp, {r0, r1, r2, r3}
        add     sp, sp, #16
        bx      lr
main:
        movs    r0, #0
        bx      lr
```

[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/KWvfecrM9)

Why is that?
I'm trying to figure out whether the references can be completely otpimized out by the compiler.
What is more interesting is that the above happened when I added more members in the `struct Foo`.

Comment: `void passFoo(Foo f)` has no observable effects, I'm surprised it's not optimized out completely.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen The same happens with optimization `-O0`

Comment: So, even with `-O0` the compiler determines that there are no observable effects and optimized everything out.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Why does it not do that when uses the reference?

Comment: Well, the compiler cannot prove that. It's modifying a field of some mysterious object that gets passed in, and the compiler does not analyze the overall code to determine that the mysterious object that gets passed in will never be used. It's much easier for the compiler to know that the option that gets passed in by value, to a function, will never be used when the function returns, because the object gets destroyed. That's what, after all, passing objects by value means.

Comment: Less instruction doesn't necessary mean faster.

Comment: It seems `Foo` goes in register when passed by value, and you just modify registers.

Comment: ***Why does it not do that when uses the reference?*** With the reference there are observable effects.

Comment: I mean, pass-by-value does something weird here. It moves stack pointer, then writes some registers into stack (only one of them is actually used anywhere), moves stack pointer back and returns. Not that any of the functions ever get called, but I still don't get why the symbol is even left in the binary.

Comment: @drescherjm What does that mean?

Comment: For the pass by reference in the calling code `int main()` the value of the x member gets set to 0. For the pass by value nothing happens to the value since a copy is passed to the functon.

Comment: @drescherjm And then the objects gets destroyed. Makes sense! Thank you